# OAuth/Authenticating user for Unity Lenses

Tags: lenses, authentication, online-accounts

Trying to create a lens that would touch a web service that requires oauth authentication.

And a search here, netted me this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses

I was using this tutorial to create a lense: http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/tutorial-on-writing-ubuntu-lensesplaces-in-python/

Speaking with a developer with more experience than myself, he mentioned using the new Online Accounts in the control center, but that there wasn't much documentation on how to do so.

Does anyone know where this documentation might exist? Or perhaps a quick tutorial/how-to/source code for handling oauth/account tokens/authentication for services in lenses?

Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know much about lens development but you could try looking at the source code of the [Photo lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-photos) in Quantal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Ubuntu API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/api/12-10/) pages, it certainly have required APIs